# How can I force Xbox Music to find music in all subfolders of my Music library?

Tags: windows-8, music, modern-ui, xbox-music

My music library is organized (roughly) like this:

```
Music
    mp3 (original)
        Artist/Album/Song
    mp3 (from Tom)
        Artist/Album/Song
    mp3 (from Dick)
        Artist/Album/Song
    mp3 (from Harry)
        Artist/Album/Song
    ... etc.
```

When I use the desktop Zune Software, it finds all of this music. However, the Xbox Music metro app only seems to find music in the "mp3 (original)" folder. How can I force it to find all of my music?

Comment: I noticed this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the most updated version (23 October 2012) of Xbox Music this has been resolved.

Comment: Did you have to do anything to make it refresh after updating to the latest version? I am still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Ah, now I see what is happening. It was indeed fixed in the latest version, but the app does not recognize "Some Band" and "The Some Band" (i.e. "American Analog Set" and "The American Analog Set") as the same artist. Hopefully this is fixed in a future update.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure all your music is listed, you have to go to

```
File Explorer -> Libraries -> Music -> Add Location
```

Include all your folders in this location and all your music will magically show up in XBox Music.

If you've already tried this, check if you are using the latest version of the app.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I explicitly include each subfolder? Because they are already subfolders of C:\Users\matth_000\Music, which is set as my Default Save Location for music.

Comment: No I did not mean that. As long as the parent folder is included and all your music are stored in it (subfolders must not cause an issue) they must be listed in XBox Music.